# Access to the path * is denied

Tags: c#, web-services, file

I have two WebServices that create files at the same director using the following method:

```
var schemaDir = _propClass.RepositorySettingRoot + @"\" + webServiceId;
if (!Directory.Exists(schemaDir))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(schemaDir);
}
var schemaFile = schemaDir + @"\" + webMethodId + ".txt";
File.WriteAllText(schemaFile, webMethodSchema);
```

When trying to delete the file using File.Delete, if it was created by the 1st service it's deleted properly, but if it was created using the second, the exception **Access to the path * is denied** is raised.

The deletion code

```
schemaDir = _propClass.RepositorySettingRoot + @"\" + webServiceId + @"\" + webMethodId + ".txt";
if (File.Exists(schemaDir))
{
    File.Delete(schemaDir);
}
```

Comment: is this a Logger functionality part?

Comment: @TomerW something like that.

Comment: Please post your deleting code.

Comment: Are you closing the file connection after writing to it? If not, ws1 might be hogging the file when ws2 wants to delete it.

Comment: @cwap using File.WriteAllText there is no need to close the file, but even if it needs, the 1st webservices works properly.
ws1 and ws2 are not accessing each other files.

Comment: Ah, okay.. Was just a top-of-the-head idea :)

Comment: Can you confirm that the exception happens on the call to `File.Delete`, not the call to `File.Exists`.

Comment: please debug, and check the value of schemaDir has illigal characters?
maybe webServiceId = null somehow?

Comment: @ChrisDickson it happens on the call to File.Delete

Comment: @TomerW no, it doesn't contain any illegal characters

Comment: Are both webservices using the same security settings, specially the Identity of the ApplicationPool?

Comment: @GTG yes, both have the same ApplicationPool.
The deletion service is unique for both webservices

Comment: Do you have the exception stack trace? What differences are there in schemaDir value between the service that works and the one that doesn't? Is one service impersonating, the other not?

Comment: I would like to see the error message and directory permissions.  I would also recommend looking at Path.Combine() instead of "" + "" + "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer ..
It's a security issue. 
The file should be deleted by the service created it.
The deletion method was on ws1, so it can delete only the files it created.